# displaying frequency distribution of all files recursively that were modified in the last 45 days

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to put these two scripts together:

This one lists all the files in all the directories:

```
dir -recurse | group-object Extension -noelement
```

And this one lists all the files that were modified after a certain date:

```
get-childitem –recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt “1/13/2008”}
```

My issue is that the second script outputs a header for every directory:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----        12/10/2012  11:21 AM            BUDGET                                                                    
d----        12/21/2012  12:38 PM            SPEND DOWN                                                                


    Directory: \\file\property\vt\Environmental Services\BUDGET\SPEND DOWN


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----        12/13/2012  12:32 PM            2012                                                                      
d----         1/29/2013   9:50 AM            2013                                                                      


    Directory: \\le\property\vt\Environmental Services\BUDGET\SPEND DOWN\2012
```

I tried to put them together like this:

```
dir -recurse | group-object Extension -noelement | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (Get-date).AddDays($somenumber)}
```

But this did not yield any results.

How can I list the counts of all the different types of files since a certain day recursively in all directories?

Here's my expected output:

```
4352    .JPG
2352    .doc
2135    .pdf
1811    .xls
1472    
857 .pub
732 .xlsx
565 .docx
66  .rtf
64  .lnk
63  .ppt
61  .url
41  .png
38  .xml
28  .htm
27  .msg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir` and `gci` are both aliases for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdLet. Just filter before grouping:

```
gci -Recurse| where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)}| group Extension -NoElement
```

Comment: that is wonderful! thank you so much. can you recommend a good powershell book?

Comment: I haven't read any PowerShell books; when starting with PowerShell, I read a lot of [Hey, Scripting Guy!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/tags/getting+started/) articles, and some of the resources at the bottom of [SO's PowerShell info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info).

Comment: thank you!! i am formulating another question, will send you a link in a minute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615060/performing-the-same-process-on-every-directory-not-recursively