# performing the same script on every directory

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have this wonderful script:

```
gci -Recurse| where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)}| group Extension -NoElement
```

The output is:

```
4352    .JPG
2352    .doc
2135    .pdf
1811    .xls
1472    
857 .pub
732 .xlsx
565 .docx
66  .rtf
64  .lnk
63  .ppt
61  .url
41  .png
38  .xml
28  .htm
27  .msg
```

what I would like is this same script to be run on every directory of the current directory (non recursive). for example if i am in directory `c:\test`, and that directory as the folder `alex`, `liza`, and `harry`, then i want this script to be applied to `c:\test\alex`, `c:\test\liza`, `c:\test\harry`

The output that I would want would be:

```
4352    .JPG    directory name
2352    .doc    directory name
2135    .pdf    directory name
1811    .xls    directory name
1472        directory name
857 .pub    directory name
732 .xlsx   directory name
565 .docx   directory name
```

How can I modify the above script to do this for every directory and append the directory name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem c:\test | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
   $folder = $_.FullName
   Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)} | Group-Object Extension -NoElement | Select-Object Name,Count,@{n='Directory';e={$folder}}
}
```

Comment: PS Z:\> Get-ChildItem z: | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{$folder = $_.FullName Get-ChildItem $_.FullN
ame -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)} | Group-Object Extension -NoElement | Select-
Object Name,Count,@{n='Directory';e={$folder}}}
Unexpected token 'Get-ChildItem' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:104
+ Get-ChildItem z: | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{$folder = $_.FullName

Comment: Get-ChildItem <<<<  $_.Full
Name -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)} | Group-Object Extension -NoElement | Selec
t-Object Name,Count,@{n='Directory';e={$folder}}}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (Get-ChildItem:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Looks like you have a space in '$_.Full Name', remove it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Does the formatting matter? If not, you can group by multiple properties.

```
gci -Recurse| 
    where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)}|
    group Extension, Directory -NoElement
```

Comment: thank you. i dont think it worked. i think it returned only the top 3-5 results for every directory

Comment: this is what the output looked like  2 .xlsx, \\kslfile\prope...
 1 .docx, \\kslfile\prope...
 2 .xlsx, \\kslfile\prope...
 2 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 2 .pdf, \\kslfile\proper...
 3 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 1 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 1 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 1 .tmp, \\kslfile\proper...
 1 .doc, \\kslfile\proper...
 2 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 1 .doc, \\kslfile\proper...
 5 .pub, \\kslfile\proper...
 2 .xlsx, \\kslfile\prope...
 8 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 1 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...
 3 .xls, \\kslfile\proper...

Comment: Sorry, I've been unavailable recently. Is the issue that the directory name is truncated on the display, or that there should be a higher extension count for each directory?